How is the friend function accessed in the case of accessing private class member?
This is a tricky tactic to access a private member of class.
But I can't get the point of declaration of friend get inside struct A_member?
#include <iostream>

struct A {
private:
  int member;
};

template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type M>
struct Rob { 
  friend typename Tag::type get(Tag) {
    return M;
  }
};

// tag used to access A::member
struct A_member { 
  typedef int A::*type;
  friend type get(A_member);
};

template struct Rob<A_member, &A::member>;

int main() {
  A a;
  a.*(get(A_member())) = 42; // write 42 to it
  std::cout << "proof: " << a.*get(A_member()) << std::endl;
}

According to the cppreference:

(only allowed in non-local class definitions) Defines a non-member function, and makes it a friend of this class at the same time.

The explicit instantiation of struct Rob has made the newly defined get a non-member function, in the closest namespace, i.e. global namespace here. So can it be accessed directly in the main?
I suppose that the get has been defined in the global namespace already by the explicit instantiation, thus I don't understand the purpose of the friend declaration of get in struct A_member.
Without this line, compiling gets error:
struct A_member { 
  typedef int A::*type;
  // friend type get(A_member);
};

<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:25:7: error: 'get' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'std::get'?

Back to the above code, it redeclare a friend get inside the struct A_member and then magically it works. What's the purpose of this friend declaration? Is there some special c++ rule that I missed?

This is not tricky... it is evil. Code like this will intentionally break a design choice and I consider it sabotage. Basically the friend system is misused to get access to the private part of A without A knowing about it. If you would use this in in a company it would reflect very badly on you.  So do NOT do this EVER!

Read this answer and the comments there.

"I have tried that, and it does not compile...." Always post complete error along with your question. Your code compiles. Post code that reproduces the error you're referring to.

@user12002570 I guess you have misunderstood my point. I updated my post.

@WeijunZhou I have read that post, thanks. But it does NOT explain my doubt.

To directly answer your question: the purpose of that friend declaration is to make it possible to call get(A_member()) via ADL. The function is defined in Rob as a hidden friend and hidden friends can only be found by the name lookup via ADL. Your new question is still a duplicate (about how hidden friends and ADL work) and usually we don't reopen questions just to reassign duplicates.

@WeijunZhou I know that ADL has kicked in this process. But why is the friend declaration in struct A_member needed here? After the explicit instantiation, the ADL should be able to lookup the non-member get, right?

It has never been declared in the namespace level, so lookup in the namespace will not find it. It is what "hidden" in the "hidden friend" means. You can simplify things a lot by changing Rob to a non-template class and define a hidden friend get there. Even if ::get is technically defined, it is not found by ADL of another arbitrary class in the namespace. Defining a hidden friend in a template followed by an instantiation essentially does the same, just in a more complicated manner.

Whether the function is defined is irrelevant. If it compiles when the function is defined, it will also compile if the function is not defined (but may fail to link). So the instantiation that makes get() "defined" is irrelevant here.

@WeijunZhou Probably I get wrong with how ADL and "hidden friend" works. Thks.

#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
private:
    int privateData;

public:
    MyClass(int data) : privateData(data) {}

    // Declare a friend function
    friend void accessPrivateData(const MyClass& obj);
};

// Definition of the friend function
void accessPrivateData(const MyClass& obj) {
    // Access private member of MyClass
    std::cout << "Private Data: " << obj.privateData << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    MyClass myObject(42);
    accessPrivateData(myObject); // Accesses private data via the friend function
    return 0;
}


This has nothing to do with the question. It does not answer OP's question. Also, this is code only answer.
